# Syntax error at select with a subquery join

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have a working postgresql query

```
select * from "A" left join (
    select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" order by "provider_id" asc, "date" desc
) B using ("provider_id") where "A"."date" >= '2022-02-17T08:31:46.781Z' order by "A"."date" desc limit 25;
```

How to build the query with knex?

I tried `.leftJoin`

```
query
  .orderBy("date", orderBy.sort)
  .limit(Math.min(limit, 1000))
  .offset(Math.min(offset, 100000))
  .leftJoin(
    this.db('B')
     .distinctOn('provider_id')
     .select('*')
     .orderBy([
       {
         column: 'provider_id',
       },
       {
         column: 'date',
         order: 'desc',
       },
    ]),
    'A.provider_id',
    'B.provider_id'
  )
```

and `.leftJoin` + `.raw`

```
query
  .orderBy("date", orderBy.sort)
  .limit(Math.min(limit, 1000))
  .offset(Math.min(offset, 100000))
  .leftJoin(
    this.db.raw('select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" order by "provider_id", "date" desc'),
    'A.provider_id',
    'B.provider_id'
  )
```

but I got the following query generated `query.toQuery()`

```
select * from "A" left join select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" order by "provider_id", "date" desc on "A"."provider_id" = "B"."provider_id" where "date" >= '2022-02-17T09:09:08.148Z' order by "date" desc limit 25
```

If I copy it and execute it on DB manually, it throws the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 62: select * from "A" left join select distinct on ("provid...
                                          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 3951
```

Knex doesn't encapsulate the subquery in `() B`. That's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to remember that raw is raw. You can use any valid query syntax in `.raw` including subqueries, parenthesis, aliases, etc.

You can hook up the left join subquery to the existing knex query object in the following way

```
query.leftJoin(
  this.db.raw(
    `(select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" where "date" >= '2022-02-17T14:45:27.827Z' order by "provider_id", "date" desc limit 10000) B`
  ),
  'A.provider_id',
  'B.provider_id'
)
```

The produced query example:

```
select a_field as aField from "A" left join (select distinct on ("provider_id") * from "B" where "date" >= '2022-02-17T14:45:27.827Z' order by "provider_id", "date" desc limit 10000) B on "A"."provider_id" = "B"."provider_id" where "A"."created_at" >= '2022-02-17T14:44:12.800Z' order by "A"."created_at" desc limit 25
```